# PHP _GET does not update dynamically with URL

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get a query param dynamically using the _GET method.

My function is looking something like this:

```
var baseURL = "http://example.org";
// clears the last query params
history.pushState("", document.title, baseURL);
// retrieves the value from the HTML code
var value = document.getElementById('id').value;

// URL with updated query params
var updatedURL = document.URL + "?value=" + value;
// pushing the new URL without refreshing the page.
history.pushState("", document.title, updatedURL);

// URL looks something like this "http://example.org?value=1"
```

But when I try to use `_GET['value']` to retrieve the value from the URL, it only gets the value the page initialized with and does not update dynamically, is there any way to retrieve this value without having to refresh the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`history.pushState()` simply changes the value of the browser URL. It doesn't actually make a server request and load the _GET variables. That's why you can't access them.

To do this without refreshing the page you would need to make an ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "yourpage.php",
  data: {value:value},
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
     // do something with the returned data
  }
});
```